# Using a business card reader to submit information to an online database

Tags: php, post, web, hardware

I was wondering if there was anyway that I could use a business card reader, and use it as some type of POST form so when it gets information it uses the POST method so I can get the information easily. If that isn't possible, is there anyway at all to get information from a card reader to a websites database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with that kind of Cloud OCR for business cards reader: http://www.card-reader.com/cloud_ocr.htm